# How to get data in SQL server into a datagrid

Tags: c#, t-sql, dbaccess

I have a sql server database that I want to bring into a datagrid. I want to use DBAccess as the way to do this. As of right now I have:
    `_dba = DBAccess("server=server;database=database;user=user;password=password")`
I need to write this data into a dataset and be able to insert and update into the database. Can anyone point me in the right direction for some tutorials or give me some advice on this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your question includes only a connectionstring. do you mean you want to write all the tables in that database to a dataset ? and if thats the case, why you need something like this ? if not, can you show us how and where did you write your select query ?

Comment: Yes, I want to write the table to a dataset. I just want to be able to query in the code and display that query in a datagrid.

Comment: I am having a problem when I bind the grid. Instead of a name showing, it is showing the guid. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/41983-ADO-Net-Architecture.aspx

it is about ado.net disconnected architecture. in the example they write a select query and give the result to a dataset. and then show it in a datagridview. i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this post, it is really easy :)

http://mka-soft.com/learn-db/44-database-tutorial-02-datagridview-an